# How do I loop through strings in R in a vectorized way

Tags: string, r, parsing

I am learning R right now and I am having trouble looping through R in a efficient manner, although I can do string parsing using for loop in a very convoluted way, but I am confused in how to write string parsing codes in a vectorized manner.

For example

```
#Social security numbers in the United States are represented by
# numbers conforming to the following format:
#
# a leading 0 followed by two digits
# followed by a dash
# followed by two digits
# followed by a dash
# finally followed by four digits
#
# For example 023-45-7890 would be a valid value,
# but 05-09-1995 and 059-2-27 would not be.
#
# Implement the body of the function 'extractSecuNum' below so that it
# returns a numeric vector whose elements are Social Security numbers
# extracted from a text, i.e., a vector of strings representing the text lines,
# passed to the function as its 'text' argument.
# (You can assume that each string in 'text' contains
# either zero or one Social Security numbers.)


extractSecuNum = function(text){
# Write your code here!

x = 1:length(text)
list_of_input = rep(0, length(text))


for (ind in x){
  list_of_input[ind] = sub(' .*', '', sub('^[^0-9]*', '', text[ind]))
}

temp = c()

for (ind in x){
  if(list_of_input[ind] != ''){
    temp = c(temp, list_of_input[ind])
  }
}

temp2 = c()
for (ind in 1:length(temp)){
  temp3 = strsplit(temp[ind], '-')
  temp2 = c(temp2, temp3)
}

final = c()

for(ind in 1:length(temp2)){
  if (sub('0[0-9][0-9]', '', temp2[[ind]][1]) == ''){
    if (sub('[0-9][0-9]', '', temp2[[ind]][2]) == ''){
      if (sub('[0-9]{4}', '', temp2[[ind]][3]) == '')
      { final = c(final, paste(temp2[[ind]][1], temp2[[ind]][2], temp2[[ind]][3], sep='-')) }
    }
    }
  }

return(final)
}
```

These are other problems with similar questions, if you look into it, you will see that the second problem is extremely complicated and non elegant

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1c68121323af19c766c

I believe the problem is that the atomic variables in R is an array, and I have no way of accessing the characters in the string

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Can you give sample input to your `extractSecuNum` that works?

Comment: `if (nchar(x <- gsub('[^0-9]', '', text)) == 9) paste(substr(x, 1, 3), substr(x, 4, 5), substr(x, 6, 9), sep = '-')` but is not robust if there are other numbers which just happen to contain exactly nine digits. This would work because the problem assumes zero or one SSNs.

Comment: @extracSecuNum `testInput = c(
'For example',
'023-45-7890',
'would be a valid value',
'but 05-09-1995',
'and 059-2-27 would not be.',
'Also 011-99-2234 is okay.'
)

correctOutput = c(
'023-45-7890',
'011-99-2234'
)` these are my test inputs and they worked

Comment: @rawr I know my solution is not rigorous, I am just trying to learn the general way of doing parsing in R right now, parsing in R is really different in parsing in python and that's a little confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extractSecuNum = function(text){
  pattern <- "0\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"
  unlist(regmatches(text,gregexpr(pattern,text)))
}

text <- paste0("fdkmsal ",
               "0",sample(10:99,10),"-",
               sample(100:999,10),"-",
               sample(1000:9999,10), " vaklra")
result <- extractSecuNum(text)

head(text)
# [1] "fdkmsal 034-965-3362 vaklra" "fdkmsal 029-190-2488 vaklra"
# [3] "fdkmsal 055-785-3898 vaklra" "fdkmsal 033-950-5589 vaklra"
# [5] "fdkmsal 025-833-9312 vaklra" "fdkmsal 054-375-5596 vaklra"
result
# [1] "034-965-3362" "029-190-2488" "055-785-3898" "033-950-5589" "025-833-9312"
# [6] "054-375-5596" "057-680-3317" "020-951-1417" "031-996-4757" "068-402-8678"
```

Comment: Is `pattern <- "0\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}" unlist(regmatches(text,gregexpr(pattern,text)))` generally the solution for doing parsing with strings (with patter regrex a little different)?